# Want to separate data types which are in int64

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fetch data types from dataframe named 'data' which are in 'int64' format. So whenever I am using code(1), it gives me results in boolean format and when I use code(2) I get desired results. Why is it happening?Please explain me the logic behind it

1)data.dtypes=='int64' -->

customer_id                        True
vintage                            True
age                                True
gender                            False
dependents                        False

2)data.dtypes[data.dtypes=='int64']--->

customer_id             int64
vintage                 int64
age                     int64

Comment: What part(s) exactly do you not understand?

Comment: This is called [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `data` is a Pandas data frame.

The property `dtypes` returns a Series containing the data type for each column in `data`.

You can learn more about this property here: [pandas.DataFrame.dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

For example, let us assume your data frame contains two columns, column_1 and column_2, where the values in the first column are floats and the values in the second column are integers and they are 64-bits in length.  A Series containing float64 and int64 would be returned when the `dtypes` property is invoked on the data frame.

You can verify this by displaying the output of `data.dtypes` which will give the following:

```
float              float64
int                  int64
dtype: object
```

Now, when you use the `==` operator, you are performing a comparison.  You are comparing what is in the Series with the value `'int64'`.  The expression will evaluate to `True` if the value in the Series matches `'int64'` and `False` otherwise.  Thus, `data.dtypes == ''int64'` will produce the following:

```
column_1    False
column_2     True
dtype: bool
```

Where column_1 and column_2 are the names of the columns in the data frame.

We can use the result of `data.dtypes == 'int64'` which is a Series containing `True` and `False` values to filter the original data frame. This is known as boolean indexing since we are using boolean values to select data.

You can learn more about it here: [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (link suggestion by [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)).

Thus, `data.dtypes[data.dtypes == 'int64']` will return only those columns where `data.dtypes == 'int64'` is `True`.

Hence, for the example above you would get the following:

```
column_2    int64
dtype: object
```